# adding subviews and constraints to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm writing my UI in code, and I'm trying to write the code for my `UICollectionViewCell` and add an `UIImageView` to it.

I need to create the `UIImageView` constraints in code.

What is the best practice for creating an imageView and constraints in an `UIICollectionViewCell`? e.i - in which `UIICollectionViewCell` creation method?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I am used to do what you're asking :

1. Create my **UICollectionViewController** class:

   ```
    class MyCollectionController: UICollectionViewController {

        let cellId = "cellId"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            collectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }


    }
   ```
2. Create your custom cell, let's call it **MyCollectionCell** :

   ```
    class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            backgroundColor = .yellow
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
   ```
3. Declare programmatically your UIImageView (I prefer right before the init func) :

   ```
    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .blue
        return iv
    }()
   ```

Don't forget the () to make sure the block of code is called!

4. We need to add the imageView to the cell view and anchor it

To do so I always use an extension on UIView containing one function called **anchor**

```
extension UIView {
    
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, topPadding : CGFloat, leftPadding: CGFloat, bottomPadding: CGFloat, rightPadding: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topPadding).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let left = left {
            self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftPadding).isActive = true
        }
          
        if let bottom = bottom {
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomPadding).isActive = true
        }
        
        if let right = right {
            self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightPadding).isActive = true
        }
        
        if width != 0 {
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        
        if height != 0 {
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can add the imageView and anchor it inside the init method of MyCollectionCell :

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topPadding: 3, leftPadding: 3, bottomPadding: 3, rightPadding: 3, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
```

5. Let's use MyCollectionCell as the cellForItemAt for MyCollectionController

In viewDidLoad, register the cell with the right class (MyCollectionCell)

```
    let cellId = "cellId"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        collectionView.register(MyCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
```

Dequeue cell as MyCollectionCell

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        
        return cell
    }
```

6. When presenting MyCollectionController, you should see this result :

[image: Expected result]